# Puzzle #3: The Maze Runners

Tags: mazes

A group of friends had heard of a strange cavern that shifts its walls every night, causing earthquakes in a remote field. Being the excited investigators that they are, they went to investigate this field. After a little bit of looking under the starlight, they found a passageway underground. They followed the paths and found something, what seemed to be a treasure in the middle. This, combined with the many corpses found within the caves, led them to believe that this treasure had something to do with the shifting of the walls. As soon as they picked up the treasure, the walls shifted and an hourglass appeared. By speculation, the hourglass had 10 minutes in its time.

The boys panicked because the caverns were decently sized and the paths have changed. But luckily, one of them had a device that showed the position of the walls. The shape of the cave now is shown below. The exit is at the top and the treasure/starting point is in the middle. Now get out and hurry!

[image]

Comment: Welp, this was posted more than $10$ minutes ago.... too late now :P

Answer (score 4):

Here it is! (As well as a badly drawn smiley face)

> The group of friends decided that if they all stuck together, they would either all make it out or be trapped in the maze... 
>  ...forever!! (Lightning strikes). 
>  
>  Thus, they decided to  split up to search through the maze, sacrificing themselves to potentially save another. 
>  
>  [image: MAZE] 
>  
>  Those two blue dots are the friends who didn't make it: Peter and Wesley. They don't get to see the smiley face, but they will always be remembered :(

Comment: Amazing job! That is a nice face too

Comment: Right before the end isn't there a shorter way?